# How to remove spaces using IndexOf?

Tags: c#, indexof

I created following to count number of words. Now I need to remove all spaces using IndexOf. I'm stuck. Can someone help? It has to be something simple, but I cant figure it out.

```
string text = "Hello. What time is it?";
int position = 0;
int noSpaces = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
{
   position = text.IndexOf(' ', position + 1);
   if (position != -1)
   { noSpaces++; }
   if (position == -1) break;
}
Console.WriteLine(noSpaces + 1);
```

Comment: What not just use `text.Trim().Split(' ');` it will return an array of words without the space?

Comment: Why must you use `IndexOf`? That seems a very strange requirement.

Comment: It's XY problem.

Comment: If you need to count the number of spaces, you can use: `using System.Linq; text.Count(char.IsWhiteSpace)`.

Comment: If you have homework that says _"use `IndexOf` to do this"_, please say so. We help folks with homework, but we're careful not to do your work for you. If it's not homework, you're going to need to tell why `IndexOf` is important to you. As others have pointed out, it's the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: The instructor told us to try to remove spaces using IndexOf. He didn't make this into an official assignment. We haven't learned Spilt() yet.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will do the research!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to just remove the spaces in your text so it would look like: `Hello.Whattimeisit?` then all you need to do is use [String.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-5.0):

```
string text = "Hello. What time is it?";

string textWithNoSpaces = text.Replace(" ", "");

Console.WriteLine(textWithNoSpaces); // will print "Hello.Whattimeisit?"
```

If you are looking to split the text into separate words then you would want to use [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0):

```
string text = "Hello. What time is it?";

string[] words = text.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); // "RemoveEmptyEntries" will remove any entries which are empty: ""

// words[0] > Hello.

// words[1] > What

// etc.
```

You then can get a count of how many words are in the text and then combine them, using [String.Concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.concat?view=net-5.0), if you need text in the form of `Hello.Whattimeisit?`:

```
int numberOfWords = words.Length;

string textWithNoSpaces = string.Concat(words);
```

Update: This is how you would count the number of words and remove spaces using [String.IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-5.0) & [String.Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-5.0):

This is a really sloppy example, but it gets the job done

```
string text = "Hello. What time is it?";

string newText = string.Empty;

int prevIndex = 0;

int index1 = 0;

int index2 = 0;

int numberOfWords = 0;

while (true)
{
    index1 = text.IndexOf(' ', prevIndex);

    if (index1 == -1)
    {
        if (prevIndex < text.Length)
        {
            newText += text.Substring(prevIndex, (text.Length - prevIndex));

            numberOfWords += 1;
        }
        break;
    }
    index2 = text.IndexOf(' ', (index1 + 1));

    if ((index2 == -1) || (index2 > (index1 + 1)))
    {
        newText += text.Substring(prevIndex, (index1 - prevIndex));

        numberOfWords += 1;
    }
    prevIndex = (index1 + 1);
}
Console.WriteLine(numberOfWords); // will print 5

Console.WriteLine(newText); // will print "Hello.Whattimeisit?"

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: @Mathhh just read in the comments of your post that you are required to use IndexOf to remove the spaces, right? If so I will add a small example on how to do it

Comment: Yes, I need to use IndexOf. Thank you again!

Comment: @Mathhh was debating whether to add this example because you should figure it out yourself, but here it is, keep in mind while it works it's definitely not the best and can be optimized, it only counts full words, so it doesn't count spaces between spaces, and removes every space which is in the text. Also, there are other ways of doing it like using StringBuilder instead of Substring, but I am assuming you already learnt about Substring

Comment: Thank you very much. This was helpful. I try to solve problems myself, but the approach I was asked to use made it confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to count the number of words, can't you try this?

```
string text = "Hello. What time is it?";
var arr = text.Split(' ');
var count = arr.Length;
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BA9M5B)

Comment: "Hello. What    [I put here 3 spaces]  time is it?", Will give you incorrect number of words :) Better add the second parameter `text.Trim().Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Comment: I'm in the very early stages of learning C#. We haven't learned Split().

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable so you cant achieve it with only IndexOf that will require multiple changes. if you need to achieve it with that particular method I think that StringBuilder is the only way. However if this is not some assignment and you plan to use it in real application I strongly dissuade because it is really process heavy.

Comment: This is a school assignment. Looking at recomendations, I now see that there are better ways to do it. I hope after this semester, we will be given some real problems to solve. Thank you for your comment.